# Android on Chromebook - BLE scan not working

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, chromium, androidappsonchromeos

I am trying to do BLE Scan on ChromeOS from my Android App. After turning on the Location Permissions I am able to get scan results. But the Manufacturer Data is not present in the results.

The Manufacturer id I have set in firmware is 0x0. I am printing the whole result object but do not see my Manufacturer Specific Data anywhere (No 0xff which is the Manu. Specific Data type)

Any one knows why this is happening?

```
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
@Override
public void onScanResult(final int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
BluetoothDevice device = result.getDevice();
int rssi = result.getRssi();
byte[] scanRecord = result.getScanRecord().getBytes();
Map<ParcelUuid, byte[]> Uuidmap = result.getScanRecord().getServiceData();

Log.i(TAG, "onScanResult- Name: " + device.getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() + " Mfg data: " + Arrays.toString(result.getScanRecord().getManufacturerSpecificData(0)));
for (Map.Entry<ParcelUuid, byte[]> entry : Uuidmap.entrySet()) {
String key = entry.getKey().toString();
byte[] value = entry.getValue();
Log.i(TAG, "UUID: " + key + " Data: " + Arrays.toString(value));
}
Log.i(TAG, "Data " + Arrays.toString(scanRecord));﻿
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I am wondering the same right now.

Comment: It seems to be working with the latest chromebook update. Though you need to re-run the scan multiple times as sometimes so results in the service data field as not populated at all.